# Statically compile LLVM tools

Tags: llvm, static-linking

I am trying to run `lli`, the LLVM JIT, on a stripped-down Linux system that does not have dynamic library support.

Going into `build.ninja` and adding the `-static` flag feels like a hack, and (at least so far) hasn't worked (it complains about PIE and PIC). Is there some better way of modifying the LLVM build instructions to compile `lli` statically? I only need that tool, not any of the other ones.

This is on LLVM 9.0.0.

Comment: [cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=false](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) and recompile IIRC.

Comment: But per http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html, default value is OFF.

Comment: The LLVM libs are being build statically – if I run `which lli`, the libraries than need to be linked are the regular Linux/C ones, not LLVM-specific ones.

Comment: Sure, looking at the build command for `lli`, it's correctly building with `libLLVM*.a`. The issue is the system libraries – `libm`, `librt`, etc. The specific error I'm getting is something about dynamic string symbols.

Comment: I can successfully compile by removing `--export-dynamic` and adding `-static`, but then the JIT can't find external symbols such as `printf`. This, I believe, is the same issue I previously encountered (and did not solve) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072075/externd-functions-not-visible-to-statically-linked-jit